# Azure Government Service Bus Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-gov

When attempting to get a managed identity token for Service Bus in Azure Gov I tried using the resource: https://servicebus.usgovcloudapi.net/ instead of https://servicebus.azure.net/ as you would for Commercial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity), but I'm getting the following error:

```
The resource principal named https://servicebus.usgovcloudapi.net/ was not found in the tenant named ___. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
```

Are you supposed to use https://servicebus.azure.net/ for managed identity in Government as well? Or is Service Bus managed identity not supported in Gov yet?

Comment: According to [the table here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities)  (third from last table) it's available, but there is no Resource ID listed, so I don't know what that means.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is odd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully got a managed identity token back in Azure Gov by using https://servicebus.azure.net/ as the resource, and it was accepted by Service Bus with the necessary RBAC applied to the managed identity.